# MySQL on XAMPP unable to run

Tags: mysql, xampp

I started using XAMPP about two days ago and out of the blue it stopped working I tried to check the error I was having that said:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:56:40  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:56:40  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:56:40  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:56:40  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:56:40  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:56:40  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

But all the fixed I found and the ones I thought might possible didn't solve the problem.
I checked the log error but didn't know what exactly is wrong 
the error log is as follow:

```
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1824338; transaction id 303
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-07-02 10:56:32 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is another app that is using the port 3306. If so, you have to kill the process and start again the mysql service.